# NodeJS- ReferenceError: wagner is not defined

Tags: node.js

I don't have experience at all with nodejs and I am learning. I have a code, which I am testing and giving me the following errors, and I don't understand why:

1) Part 3 Assessment Tests "before all" hook:
     ReferenceError: wagner is not defined
      at Object. (fx.js:2:31)
      at Object. (dependencies.js:3:10)
      at Context. (test.js:29:20)

2) Part 3 Assessment Tests "after all" hook:
     TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined
      at Context. (test.js:65:11)

These are the programs involved in the issue:

test.js --------------

```
var assert = require('assert');
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var status = require('http-status');
var superagent = require('superagent');
var wagner = require('wagner-core');

var URL_ROOT = 'http://localhost:3000';
var PRODUCT_ID = '000000000000000000000001';

describe('Part 3 Assessment Tests', function() {
  var server;
  var app;
  var succeeded = 0;
  var finalCharge;

  var Category;
  var Config;
  var fx;
  var Product;
  var Stripe;
  var User;

  before(function() {
    app = express();

    // Bootstrap server
    models = require('./models')(wagner);
    dependencies = require('./dependencies')(wagner);

    // Make models available in tests
    var deps = wagner.invoke(function(Category, fx, Product, Stripe, User, Config) {
      return {
        Category: Category,
        fx: fx,
        Product: Product,
        Stripe: Stripe,
        User: User,
        Config: Config
      };
    });
...
```

dependencies.js -------------

```
var wagner = require('wagner-core');
var fs = require('fs');
var fx = require('./fx')(wagner);
var Stripe = require('stripe');

module.exports = function(wagner) {
  var stripe = 

  // TODO: Make Stripe depend on the Config service and use its `stripeKey`
  // property to get the Stripe API key.
  wagner.factory('Stripe', function() {
    return Stripe(Config.stripeKey);
  });

  wagner.factory('fx', fx);

  wagner.factory('Config', function() {
    return JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./config.json').toString());
  });

  var Config = wagner.invoke(function(Config) {
      return Config;
   });
};
```

fx.js --------------------------

```
var superagent = require('superagent');
var _ = require('underscore')(wagner);

module.exports = function(Config) {
...
};
```

I think I shouldn't have any problem because wagner is defined on test.js and passed as parameter to dependencies.js, and it is passing it on to fx.js.

1- Could you tell me what is wrong in the code ?
2- The second error, I have not cue why is it happening.

Please, help

Comment: what are the contents of package.json or node_modules? did you install wagner with npm install?

Comment: package.json {
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "1.12.4",
    "express": "4.12.3",
    "express-session": "1.11.2",
    "http-status": "0.1.8",
    "mongoose": "4.0.3",
    "passport": "0.2.2",
    "passport-facebook": "2.0.0",
    "stripe": "3.3.4",
    "superagent": "1.2.0",
    "underscore": "1.5.2",
    "wagner-core": "0.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "3.8.11",
    "gulp-mocha": "2.0.1",
    "mocha": "2.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "check-credentials": "mocha part1.js",
    "test": "mocha test.js",
    "watch": "gulp watch"
  }
}

Comment: Yes. wagner was installed as part of the package.json with nlm install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to use `wagner` in fx.js before you execute the exported function and outside of the scope that `wagner` is passed to. Also, `Config` seems a bit misleading if you're passing `wagner` to that function instead.

If you can defer loading underscore, you could do something like:

```
var superagent = require('superagent');
var _;

module.exports = function(Config) {
  if (!_)
    _ = require('underscore')(Config);
  // ...
};
```

Answer (score 4):

In your dependencies.js, in the fx definition, you dont need to pass wagner as parameter, because that variable doesnt exist there:

```
var fx = require('./fx');
```

As i see, you already defined the Config factory, and you dont need to assign it to a variable for use it, because wagner will autoinject your "Config" factory, allowing you access to it:

```
wagner.factory('Stripe', function(Config) {
    return Stripe(Config.stripeKey);
});

...

wagner.factory('Config', function() {
   return JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./config.json').toString());
});
```

Then in your fx.js, when you wanna use the Config parameter you just pass it:

```
module.exports = function(Config) {
    var url = 'http://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=' +
    Config.openExchangeRatesKey;
 ...
}
```

Exactly the same you should do if you wanna use the "Config" factory in any other file:

```
[auth.js]
function setupAuth(User, Config, app) {
    ...
}
```